# GLEW and VS 2012 : unresolved external symbols

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-studio-2012, glew

I tried all the answers to similar questions on SO and nothing worked.
I compiled the binaries from source myself using VS2012, I copied the`.lib.` file, `.dll` file and the `.h`.

here are the errors I am getting

```
error LNK1120: 5 unresolved externals 
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___GLEW_VERSION_3_3 
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _glewExperimental 
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol glewGetErrorString@4 referenced in function main 
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol glewGetString@4 referenced in function main 
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol glewInit@0 referenced in function main
```

I am using windows 8 64 bits, but my visual studio is 32 bits.
I am also using `freeglut` library, but no errors about it.
any ideas ?

Comment: Well, copying is not enough. You've to tell the linker to actually use the `.lib` file as well (some libraries have a `#pragma` in their headers that does this, but the clean solution is to add the linker statement explicitly).

Comment: So I should add an additional dependency?

Comment: IIRC dependencies in VS operate on the source file level. No, you should open Project settings→Linker Options→Libraries and add `glew.lib` to the set of libraries linked to your program.

Comment: I can't find it, there is a field to add "library directories " but no "additional libraries " field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your `.lib` files in the default include directory for libraries.
for VS 2013 it is
`...\Visual Studio 12.0\VC\lib` for X86.
`...\Visual Studio 12.0\VC\lib\amd64` for X64 architecture.
Then go to `Project Properties`→`Configuration Properties`→`Linker`→`Input` and edit the field named `Additional Dependencies`. see the pictures

[image]

Comment: Installing libraries in the toolchain's (VS in that case) directories has a fair share of problems; most notabely that updating the toolchain may delete or otherwise render the additional libraries unusable. Usually one installed 3rd party libraries in a auxiliary directory and adds that to the project library search directories.